# LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle how it works

Tags: symfony

I don't understand  how it works the **LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle** i implemented the **LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle** in my code that is running but i don't understand why, makes me confusion for example this code.

I did not have any function for /login_check

```
 form_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
```

Can someone explain ? (I am new in symfony)

Sorry my English

Answer (score 0):

This function is in the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle. You handle this route by setting:

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

in the `routing.yml` file. More info in [docs](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/bd9040f6b073c8e7d075280d2f6aa2e1711541e6/Resources/doc/index.md#configuration%20docs).

Answer (score 0):

The [check_path](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#check-path) route/path is used by your firewall to catch login requests.

This route's action is never really accessed. It's the route/url your login form posts to and the request should be processed by your firewall's provider service.

If the check_path route's action is being executed there is something wrong with the firewall (the request is not processed by your firewall).

Finally, `/login_check` is the default route